Trigger timer from interrupt and start timer inside timer callback (nucleo STM)
I want to initiate timer alfa from an interrupt. Once the timer period elapses, I want to start another timer within the callback.
Here is the code for this setup:
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    switch (GPIO_Pin) {
    case ALFA_Pin:
        if (ALFA_TIMER.State == HAL_TIM_STATE_READY) {
            HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&ALFA_TIMER);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim == &ALFA_TIMER) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&BETA_TIMER);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&BETA_TIMER);
    }

    if (htim == &BETA_TIMER) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&BETA_TIMER);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&BETA_TIMER);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&ALFA_TIMER);
    }
}

The second timer is not responding correctly.

please specify the programming language, the actual response in logs, the expected response in logs.

C programming language. I track the timer with an oscilloscope. The question is if the stuct of code is correct

suggest to insert trace messages into log file. explain the actual against the expected. the info provided is insufficient.
